# read from multitrack audio recorder in code

Tags: audio-recording

(Ubuntu 18.04)

I want to write c/c++ code to read, in realtime, audio data from a multitrack audio recorder (specifically the zoom f8n, but am open to getting a different one), plugged in via usb.

I've no idea how to go about doing this. I'd like to use the library 'rtaudio' (I've also installed ALSA), but it can't seem to read from the device. Is there some underlying driver that can do it? Do multitrack recorders tend to support some standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...well then, turns out ALSA can, in fact, do it. But not fun. If anybody goes down this route: when you call send_pcm_read_i, it reads frames, not bytes. A frame = 1,2,or whatever bytes per sample per channel, in 'interleaved mode', which is what worked for me. So you'd get { 2bytes, 2bytes, 2bytes } for 3-channel, 16-bit audio, per frame.